# Generalized Lokta Volterra Model in python

Tags: python, math, ode

I am currently working on a generalized Lokta Volterra model to represent microbial communities. However I am struggling to do so.

This is the Lokta Volterra equation used in a couple papers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFVaT.png)

Does anyone have an idea on how to code the gLV equation above?

The problems I am running into

1. Using the right method to solve the ODE
2. Adding the matrix into the function for the

Does anyone have an idea on how to code the gLV equation above?
I tried doing the following code but I am sure it is not the way to do it

```python
def gLV(X,t, r, a):
    x= X
    
    dx = x *(r+a*y)
    
    return dx

Nt=100
tmax=300
t=np.linspace(0., tmax, Nt)
x0=4
r=1
a=1

res=integrate.odeint(gLV, x0,t,args=(r,a))
x = res.T
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost correct. Just consider that `*` in python-numpy is always term-wise multiplication, `a*b` is the array with entries `a[k]*b[k]`, similar to `a+b`. This is what is wanted for the "outer" product, the "inner" is proper matrix-vector product.

Assuming a recent version of python 3, the correct way is

```
def gLV(X,t, r, A):
    return X * (r + A @ X)
```

Other, older notation for the product is `np.matmul(A,X)` or `A.dot(X)`. Do not mix arrays as vectors and matrices as (row, column) vectors.